# Convert seconds to fractional hours (half hour being .50 and not 30)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following method to convert a duration in seconds to hours. For example, 2 hours and a half would result in 2.30 Also, 2 hours and fifteen minutes would result in 2.15. So it outputs number of hours and number of minutes.

I want to modify the method to display 2.5 or 2.25 instead of the above. I need to do it that way to make calculations. For example, if there is a $30/hr salary and employee worked 10 hours and a half, I need to multiply `30*10.5` and not `30*10.30`.

```
def hour_quantity
  unless self.duration.blank?
    hours = (self.duration/60)/60
    minutes = (self.duration/60) % 60
    hours.to_s + '.' + minutes.to_s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jon is correct, as usual. Just use floating point division:

```
def hour_quantity
  duration / 3600.0
end
```

When displaying, you might want to round:

```
puts '%.2f' % hour_quantity
```

This will give you 2 decimal places, always (e.g. "2.00", "2.25", "2.50"). Alternatively:

```
  puts '%g' % hour_quantity
  puts '%g' % 2.0           #=> "2"
  puts '%g' % 2.25          #=> "2.25"
  puts '%g' % 2.4999999     #=> "2.5"
```

Comment: ah! thanks true! after a day of coding the brain stops working properly :P

Comment: I think that method gives me the amount of hours but it doesn't give me the .50 if it includes a half hour. it only outputs integers.

Comment: If you divide by a float you will get a float, which will then be rounded by `"%.2f"`; if you don't want an even number of hours to be `2.00` you can just `"%g" % hour_fraction` to get `2.5`

Comment: @leonel: It outputs *numbers* (floating point, in that case, so probably something like 10.5). If you want to show these numbers to the user, you need to format them as a string. This is what `"%.02f" % num` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Rails 6.1.0** you can do:

```rb
1800.seconds.in_hours # => 0.5
15.minutes.in_hours # => 0.25
```

These are the methods that were newly introduced: [in_seconds](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_seconds), [in_minutes](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_minutes), [in_hours](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_hours), [in_days](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_days), [in_weeks](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_weeks), [in_months](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_months), and [in_years](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_years).